# how to display PopupWindow centered to clicked point on screen?

Tags: android, onclick, popupwindow, gravity

I´ve recently implemented a PopupWindow that was displayed exactly on a position where I clicked my GoogleMapv2.
I converted LatLng map location to screenlocation, set gravity to center and displayed on screen. Then, without any change in code, it started displaying a bit above the clicked point and I don´t know what´s wrong. Please, help! I am eager to any solution ot my problem, I actually just want to display a progress dialog to the clicked point on a map.

Here is my code:

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point)
            {       
    View popUpView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup, null); 
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) popUpView.findViewById(R.id.popup);
      ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(MainActivity.this);        
          progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dialog));
    layout.addView(progressBar);

    mpopup = new PopupWindow(popUpView, 30,30, false); //Creation of popup
    mpopup.setOnDismissListener(MainActivity.this);
    mpopup.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);             
    pinToScreen(point, popUpView);
            }
        });
    }
}

private void pinToScreen(LatLng point, View popupView)
{
    Projection projection = mMap.getProjection();       
    Point pixPoint = projection.toScreenLocation(point);
    LatLng latlng=projection.fromScreenLocation(pixPoint);
    DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int screenwidth = dm.widthPixels;
    int screenheight = dm.heightPixels;     
    mpopup.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER,
                                  pixPoint.x-screenwidth/2, pixPoint.y-screenheight/2;      
}
```

R.layout.popup:

```
LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/popup"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:layout_gravity="center">
LinearLayout>
```

ProgressDialog drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:shape="oval"
android:visible="true"
android:innerRadius="60dp"

><solid 
    android:color="@color/skypicker_blue1"       
    />
<stroke android:color="@color/transparent_blue2"
    android:width="1dp"/>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the application was not displayed on fullscreen, so the screenpoint converted from clicked LatLng did not correspond with the actual screenpoint, the offset was the height of the top panel on Android. When I made the app fullscreen, it helped. However, I still don´t know hot to get height of the Android top panel...